# How do I take the reciprocal of all non-zero entries in a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, masking

I am trying to take the reciprocal of every non zero value in a numpy array but am messing something up.  Suppose:

```
norm = np.arange(0,11)
```

I would like the np.array that would be (maintaining the zeros in place)

```
[ 0, 1, 0.5 , 0.33, 0.25, 0.2 , 0.17, 0.14, 0.12, 0.11, 0.1]
```

If I set

```
mask = norm !=0
```

and I try

```
1/norm[mask]
```

I receive the expected result of

```
[1, 0.5 , 0.33, 0.25, 0.2 , 0.17, 0.14, 0.12, 0.11, 0.1]
```

However I'm trying to understand why is it that when I try the following assignment

```
norm[mask] = 1/norm[mask]
```

i get the following numpy array.

```
[0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

any ideas on why this is or how to achieve the desired np.array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you didn't accidentally change the value of `norm`.

Both

```
mask = norm != 0
norm[mask] = 1 / norm[mask]
```

and

```
norm[norm != 0] = 1 / norm[norm != 0]
```

both do exactly what you want them to do.  I also tried it using `mask` on the left side and `norm != 0` on the right side like you do above (why?) and it works fine.

EDIT BY FY:  I misread the example.  I thought original poster was starting with [0, .5, .333, .25] rather than with [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]. Poster is accidentally creating an int64 array rather than a floating point array, and everything is rounding down to zero.  Change it to `np.arange(0., 11.)`

Comment: hey thanks for checking.  Yes any time i do the assignment norm[mask] = 1/ norm[mask] I get the np.array [0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] rather than 1/norm[mask] preceded by a zero.  This is after redefining norm to avoid the error you mentioned. (you're right about the mask vs norm!=0 i'll edit it above)   Is this the exact code you're entering?

Comment: I edited code above.  I misread your original example.

Comment: thanks! why is it that it creates the right floating point answer with the calculation alone, but with the assignment norm[mask] = 1/norm[mask] it rounds down?  is it because in the latter case it then has to revert to the format of the original array?

Comment: That sounds like a reasonable explanation.

Answer (score 1):

another option is using `numpy.reciprocal` as documented [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reciprocal.html) with a parameter `where` as followed:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.reciprocal(data,where= data!=0)
```

---

example:

```
In[1]: data = np.array([2.0,4.0,0.0])
in[2]: np.reciprocal(data,where=data!=0)
Out[9]: array([0.5 , 0.25, 0.  ])
```

notice that this function is not intended to work with `ints`, therefore the initialized values are with the `.0` suffix.
if you're not sure of the type, you can always use `data.astype(float64)`